# Poles of a function and asymptotic approximation

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, asymptotics, laplace-transform

I'm studying the book An introduction ot infinite dimensional linear system Theory by Curtain and Zawart.

In page 199, exercise 4.15, the authors claim that the poles, $p_{n}$, of

$G(s) = \frac{e^{\frac{-s}{2}}}{s(s+\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-s})}$

assymptotically $p_{n}\simeq -\log (4n-3)\pm \frac{\pi}{2}(4n-3)i$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I know that $G$ has a pole in $s=0$ and infinitely many poles in $s=W_{k}(-\frac{\pi}{2})$, where $W_{k}$, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, is the $k$-th branch of the Lambert W function. However, I have no idea how they found that asymptotic approximation. Anyone can help me?

Additionally, I am wondering if this expression could be generalized for

$G(s) = \frac{e^{\frac{-s}{2}}}{s(s+a e^{-s})}$

where $a$ is a nonzero constant.

Thanks in advance.

Gustavo

Comment: Look at formula (4.20) in https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the tip! truncating the series (4.20) and computing it numerically I get results very close to the above expression, but I couldn't get the explicit expression.

Comment: If you substitute the approximation into $s e^s$, you get $$
 - \frac{\pi }{2} \mp i\frac{{\log (4n - 3)}}{{4n - 3}}$$
which is asymptotic to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for large $n$.

Comment: I think I did not understand what you mean by substituting the approximation into $se^{s}$.  You meant to substitute $$W_{k}(z) = \log (z) + 2\pi i k - \log(\log(z) + 2\pi i k)$$ or the whole series? In this case, $$se^{s} = \log (-\pi/2) + 2\pi i k - \log(\log(-\pi/2) + 2\pi i k).$$  This is where I got stucked. If you could explain the details it would help me a lot. Sorry for not being very familiar with this.